# How to get total workspace (team) user count via Slack API?

Tags: slack-api

I am trying to get the total number of users within a Slack workspace. Just the count.

**Things I've considered:**

- Iterating over the [`users.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list)

  - Unnecessarily heavy on the API and gets me waaaay more data than I need (the less I know about the users, the better imo)
  - Includes inactive users (so cannot get a proper indication without iterating over *everything*)
- Using [`conversations.info`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.info)

  - Requires a scope that I currently don't use (`channels:read`). Getting read access to channels seems like a very intrusive permission (even though my app doesn't use it and I don't want to scare off users by requesting this sort of information).

Is there an easier way to getting this information or any ideas I have not considered yet? Let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a call to `[conversations.members][1]` for the #general channel. It won't return a total number of users but it will return a list of all user ids pertaining to members of that channel, you'd just need count the ids on your end. Every user on a workspace is automatically added to the #general channel. No one can leave that channel nor can it be deleted or archived so it's sure to have the most accurate count of total workspace users. The `conversations.members` method does require the `channels:read` scope though so that's something to keep in mind.